# When I create a GIF in Photoshop CS5 the animation is gone when I re-open the file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I am running Windows 10, using Photoshop CS5. I have been using Photoshop every day for several years, but am self-taught, so I am not an expert.

I've read other questions like mine, so I would like to clarify first that I know HOW to create a GIF in Photoshop. I know how to save it (via "Save for web and devices", etc.) There is nearly almost always transparency in my GIF creations. I know how to set the frame delay time.

Also, there are SOME gifs, both that I have created in Photoshop, or have gotten elsewhere, that I have no trouble opening and viewing the animation.

Another thing to note is that I can still see the animation when I open it in another viewer that support GIF files. But when I then attempt to open it in Photoshop, it has the same number of frames, but every one is a duplicate of the first frame.

The only other think that I can think of that you might need to know is that I know nothing about working with the Timeline Animation. I have only ever used the Frame by Frame animation.

PLEASE! Somebody out there must be able to help me! This has been a problem for so long because after creating a GIF I often need to resize it to insert it in a video I am creating (I create e-cards). I am desperate!

Comment: Opening a GIF in Photoshop that is animated requires different steps. I forgot exactly what it was, hench this is a comment and not an answer. I do not have time to research it right now, but if you google Photoshop open animated gif, you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

To open an animated GIF in Photoshop use File > Import > Video Frames to Layers. Navigate to the file, select it and click Open.

In the dialog box Import Video to Layers there are some options about the range to import or the frames to skip.

You can open the Timeline in Window menu. The Timeline has more options and the controls to play the animation.